# Show OrderIDs and which customer placed each order use JOIN ON statements in this query

Tags: sql

I get a syntax error in `FROM` clause. These are my tables:

[image: Tables and attributes]

This is according to my professor's notes he want us to use.

```
SELECT orderID
FROM orders
JOIN customers ON customers.customerID = orders.customerID
ORDER BY Customername
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The error message is syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: My professor specifically asked to use this site: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: You have some invisible character or something in your query because when I copied it to the link you posted it works fine. Just copy the query from here and run it again

Comment: Is still gives me the same syntax error in FROM clause. Do you know if using on FireFox has anything to do with it?

Comment: I tried in on google chrome and it gave me 196 orderID results. It might have been the setting on FireFox or something. But does the SQL seem correct based on the picture? Write  a  query to show a  list  of  OrderIDs  and  which  customer placed  each  order  (organized alphabetically  by  Customername). UseJOIN  ON  Statementin  this  query.

Comment: I got the orderID results, but I feel as if I'm missing the customername part. I'm not sure what to add to give me results containing customername.

Comment: Just add customername to your SELECT. Don’t you have a textbook that explain the basics of sql and select queries?

Comment: Joakim Danielson, unfortunately my professor didn't assign a textbook for the summer class. This is my first time taking a class that invovles using SQL for the MBA program, so I apologize if I ask the obvious questions, but I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seem to work fine. I would suggest naming your tables when joining, it makes it easier to keep track of variables used, see below:

```
SELECT a.orderID
FROM orders a
JOIN customers b ON b.customerID = a.customerID
ORDER BY b.Customername
```

Comment: When you type that code in do you get any result for customer name?

Comment: No, with this code you will only get orderID from the orders-table. In order to also get customer name, write "a.orderID, b.CustomerName" inbetween the select- and the from-statements.

Comment: Thank you Kinzerb! I have another question using the same screenshot table as reference.

Comment: Write  a  query to  show SupplierID  and SupplierName  of  suppliers  with  SupplierID  greater than  2 but  smaller  than 10  [Use  WHERE  BETWEEN  AND; Please note that the  clause  between  X  and Y includesboth X and Y, so you have to change it to between X+1 and Y-1 to satisfy the requirement]. How many records do you get after you run your query?

Comment: The please note is a little confusing to me on whether or not he wants to include 2 and 10 or not. So far the SQL query I have is:
SELECT SupplierID, SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE SupplierID=2 OR SupplierID=5 OR SupplierID=8

Comment: You are almost correct, write it like this: SELECT SupplierID, SupplierName FROM Suppliers WHERE SupplierID BETWEEN 3 AND 9.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance Kinzerb! I really appreciate it! You've been an amazing help!